# HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently from the IIS for two minutes

Tags: iis, http, rewrite, iis-8, 301-redirect

The IIS for two minutes was redirecting from `www.exaple.com` to `www.example.com`.  Nobody fixed it - it was a temporary fault.

There is URL Rewrite 2.0 installed which has one rule which was not changed for years and everything was fine until last Monday. For two minutes there was a redirection loop and the site was down.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type : text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location : http://www.exaple.com/
Server : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-UA-Compatible : IE=edge,chrome=1
Date : Sun, 25 Sep 2016 23:15:11 GMT
Content-Length : 142
```

Event logs are clear - nothing from .NET, aps, system.

Did you encounter something like this before? What could be the reason?